# Possible for Android JUnit test to create a config file in the target apps data directory?

Tags: android, junit, robotium

I would like my Robotium test to create a configuration file for the application I am testing to read. The file would be located in the internal storage /data directory associated with the tested application.

Is this possible? At the moment I am getting a "Permission denied" error.

Comment: According to the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), I doubt it is doable at application runtime. try using external storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* actually possible to create files in data storage outside of an applications designated area. However, if these files are already generated by the target application, they must have WRITABLE permissions to enable the test application to modify them.

In my case my application does not generate the files, so this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Write shell script and push your file with adb root command.
If that doest not help you -create file inside your test.

Comment: The shell script would work, but it's not particularly elegant. Creating a file inside my test application would not work, as the target application needs to read it (this configuration file needs to be located within the target application).